# How to select a range diagonally in Excel?

Tags: excel, dashboard, business-objects, xcelsius

Hi I have a simple question, how to select a range diagonally in Excel, let's say I need to select (a3 and b1) or (a3 and b2) or simply a1 and b2, I need this range for SAP dashboard design (xcelsius) and Holding down a control key was NOT an Option!!

Thanks

Comment: Why is Ctrl key not an option?  That's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a range diagonally.
In your situation I think the best option is to get the range you want and copy to a column using a formula.

For example, if you want to select a1, b2 and c3. In cell d1 put =if(a1="";"";a1), in cell d2 =if(b2="";"";b2) and in cell d3 =if(c3="";"";c3).
Then you select d1 to d3.

Answer (score 0):

I made a userform to select any number of cells in any direction. I don't know use of this.

```
Option Explicit
'Run this to open Userform named "Select_Diago"
Sub open_form()
Select_Diago.Show
End Sub
```

This thing will pop up then

[image]

Enter the number of cells to select and direction in which it need to be selected (default is set to right down)

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim Direction As String
Select_Diago.Hide
Direction = "SE"
If NE.Value = True Then Direction = "NE"
If SE.Value = True Then Direction = "SE"
If SW.Value = True Then Direction = "SW"
If NW.Value = True Then Direction = "NW"
Call Select_Diagonal(Direction, TextBox1.Value - 1)
End Sub

Sub Select_Diagonal(Direction As String, Num As Integer)
Dim Diagonal As Range, i As Integer
Dim StrEx As String
'Num = InputBox("How Many cells would you like to select diagonally?")
Select Case Direction
Case "SW"
'For SW
For i = 0 To Num
    On Error Resume Next
    StrEx = StrEx + (Split(Cells(, ActiveCell.Column - i).Address, "$")(1)) + CStr((ActiveCell.Row + i)) + ","
Next i
Case "SE"
'For SE
For i = 0 To Num
    On Error Resume Next
    StrEx = StrEx + (Split(Cells(, ActiveCell.Column + i).Address, "$")(1)) + CStr((ActiveCell.Row + i)) + ","
Next i
Case "NE"
'For NE
For i = 0 To Num
    On Error Resume Next
    StrEx = StrEx + (Split(Cells(, ActiveCell.Column + i).Address, "$")(1)) + CStr((ActiveCell.Row - i)) + ","
Next i
Case "NW"
'For NW
For i = 0 To Num
    On Error Resume Next
    StrEx = StrEx + (Split(Cells(, ActiveCell.Column - i).Address, "$")(1)) + CStr((ActiveCell.Row - i)) + ","
Next i
End Select
StrEx = Left(StrEx, Len(StrEx) - 1)
ActiveSheet.Range(StrEx).Select
End Sub
```

**Result 1:**
[image]

**Result 2:**
[image]

Comment: nice use of the radio buttons to make it intuitive.